# Am I using if, elseif and else incorrectly?

Tags: php

Here is the code to start with:

```
*<?php
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM DistributorCourses WHERE Distributor = '". $Distributor ."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $sql_query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    echo '<div class="row">';
        echo '<div class="col-md-12">';
            echo '<table class="table">';
            if($count > 1) {
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<th>Course Title</th> ';
                    echo '<th>Price</th>';
                    echo '<th>Purchase</th>';
                echo '</tr>';
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['Title'] .'</td> ';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['Price'] .'</td> ';
                        if ($row['Title'] == $course && in_array("". $row['Title'] ."", $descriptions)) {
                            echo '<td><a href="#" title="Retake Exam" class="btn btn-warning">Retake Exam</a></td>';
                        }

                        elseif (in_array("". $row['Title'] ."", $descriptions)) {
                            echo '<td><a href="#" title="You have already purchased this course!" class="btn btn-default" style="background: #e6e6e6; border: 1px solid #adadad; cursor: default;">You have already purchased this course!</a></td>';
                        }

                        else {
                            echo '<td><a href="purchase.php?courseid='. $row['CourseID'] .'&title='. $row['Title'] .'" title="" class="btn btn-success">Purchase Course</a></td>';
                        }
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            }
            echo '</table>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
?>*
```

This code works brilliantly however... The first `elseif` statement does not work and I do not understand why. Can anyone figure out why?

I have an array which is `$descriptions`, I want to make it so if the Course Title `($row['Title'])` is in `$descriptions`, to display "Retake Exam" as shown. At the moment it still says 'You have already purchased this course!'.

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM CustomisePage WHERE Distributor = '$Distributor'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $sql_query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count == 1) {
    $Image = $row['Image'];
    $ImageAlt = $row['ImageAlt'];
    $headercolour = $row['headercolour'];
    $footercolour = $row['footercolour'];
}

$sql_query1 = "SELECT order_description FROM single_user_orders WHERE username = '". $_SESSION['login_user'] ."'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $sql_query1);
$count1 = mysqli_num_rows($result1);

if($count1 >= 1) {
    while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        $descriptions[] = $row1['order_description'];
    }
}

$sql_query2 = "SELECT pass_or_fail, course FROM single_user_exam_results WHERE user_on_course = '". $_SESSION['login_user'] ."'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $sql_query2);
$count2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

if($count2 >= 1) {
    while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $passfail[] = $row2['pass_or_fail'];
        $course[] = $row2['course'];
    }
}
```

Comment: we've no way of knowing what `$course`, `$Distributor`, `$row['Title']`, `$descriptions` are.

Comment: Check each variable and see if all of them corespond to your logic.

Comment: Why do you add a empty string before and after the `$row['Title']`? Thats nonsense. Where do you set `$course`?

Comment: why `in_array("". $row['Title'] ."",` in 2 double quotes?

Comment: Tehre are 3 queries before hand. I have updated.

Comment: Just check whats inside of `$course`. As you can see `in_array("". $row['Title'] ."", $descriptions)` is true. Then is the problem at `$course`.

Comment: `"The first elseif statement does not work"` - Define "does not work".  What is it doing, and what do you expect it to be doing?  How have you validated this behavior?  The `elseif` keyword in PHP *does* "work".  If your values aren't what you expect them to be, that's not really a PHP bug.

Comment: Well if $row['Title'] is the same as a Title in the $courses array it should fall in to the if statement and show Retake Exam, which it doesn't when I know there is a Title that I have failed in the $course array... It seems to miss this if statement and use the elseif statement instead even though $row['Title'] is equal to a value in the $courses array.

Comment: I think  $row['Title'] and $descriptions is enough inside in_array()  why you are giving empty double quotes and concatenations... bla bla

Comment: @user6618037 Is `$course` a `array`? That is the answer. You cant compare a `string` with a `array`. You can do a in_array around this.

Comment: @PatrickMlr, $course is an array, yes. I am trying to say if $row['Title'] exists in the $course array then echo this out... How can I do that?

Comment: @user6618037 You did it after this expression. The `in_array($row['Title'], $course)` does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I see this right, you said that $course is an array. Just do the same with this like you did after that.

From:

```
if ($row['Title'] == $course && in_array("". $row['Title'] ."", $descriptions)) {
```

To:

```
if (in_array($row['Title'], $course) && in_array($row['Title'], $descriptions)) {
```

That could do the thing.

Comment: Why couldn't I do that... Thank you so much!!!!!!!